# Webstorm generator function not accepted

Tags: ide, generator, webstorm, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to use `iojs` with `koa`, what works well. But `Webstorm` doesn't accept the generator functions as valid.

```
/** gets marked as syntactically invalid code */
app.use(function *() {
    this.body = 'Hello World';
});
```

My actual version is `Webstorm 9`.
Is there maybe a workaround? I couldn't find a matching option for it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to the `Preferences` > `Languages & Frameworks` > `JavaScript` and chose `ECMAScript 6` for `JavaScript language version`.