# WebStorm autocomplete with NodeJS and Koa js

Tags: node.js, autocomplete, webstorm, koa

It may sounds like a joke, but I'm really demoralized with several things about Autocomplete in WebStorm.

1. When I try to put Generator-function into koajs `use` method, I get error.
2. There is no autocomplete with Koa JS methods.

I tried to fix problem with TypeScript-definitions, but It is not work.

[image: Autocomplete is not provided]

But if I create Koa instance with `new`, autocomplete will appears.
[image]

But another problem appears.
[image]

This code works good, but I'm demoralized with these errors and can't write my project.... :( Help me!

P.S. I have set ES6 standard in JavaScript settings.

Comment: What version of Koa are you using?

Comment: Judging from the generator function (and lack of `convert`), my guess is he's using Koa v1.

Comment: I believe you need to use `new Koa();` instead of just `Koa();` ever since they changed it to be an ES6 class in their codebase. The error about the generator function might be due to the fact that Koa is moving away from generator-based middleware. Try changing `app.use(function *(next) { /* stuff */ });` to `app.use(async (ctx, next) => { /* stuff */ });` If it still has an issue with that, try removing the `async` word.

Comment: @saadq In all cases the same error

Comment: So even when you do `app.use((ctx, next) => { ... });` You get an error that says `Argument type Function is not assignable to parameter type GeneratorFunction`? In that case it seems to be saying that you definite *are* using Koa v1, and that you're passing a regular function instead of a generator. That's weird because then the code in your image should be working. The only relevant thing I've found is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28131742/webstorm-generator-function-not-accepted), but you say that you have ES6 in your settings so I'm not sure at this point unfortunately.

Comment: @saadq Yes I have this error for all cases. Yes, I have set ES6 in JavaScript settings. But the error is not lost (